# How to compute relative difference in a circular domain (weekday) in R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, modulo

I would like to find the relative distance from a given day of week to another day of week. Assume the following R input of relative differences from day 0, in days:

```
day <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
```

The domain has a periodicity of one week (thus 7 days). I would like to get the following values:

```
relativedist <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```

using modulo is a natural first guess, but as expected, not correct - it does not work for circular domains:

```
day%%4
```

results in

```
[1] 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2
```

I looked at packages `circular` and `circStats`, but failed to find an applicable function.

Comment: A clumsy approach I htought off is using lookup maps: 
    `modMap <- c(0,1,2,3,3,2,1)
    names(modMap) <- 0:6` but it does not work well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the `pmin` function will give the correct answer but your data is arranged to start and stop at a natural boundary, so you will need to make sure it's as general as you need (it did deliver the same sequence with 1:20 as input as the diffFromNearest function offered by @NickK):

```
> pmin( day %% 7, rev(day)%%7)
 [1] 0 1 2 3 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 3 2 1 0
```

The `pmin` and `pmax` functions do "side-by-side comparisons of two vectors.

This implements the logic in @NickK's procedure using `pmin` and modulus arithmetic:

```
pmin( day %% 7, (7-day)%%7)


> replicate( 20, {day = sample(1:30, 20); identical( pmin( day %% 7, (7-day)%%7), 
                                                     diffFromNearest(day, 7) )} )
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[16] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: I agree that @BondedDust's second piece of code works, and is a slightly terser way of achieving what I was doing above. It's also about 2.5x quicker using `pmin` than `ifelse` (as tested using microbenchmark).

Comment: I like the updated answer with pmin - and it works, tested on non-natural bounds

Answer (score 2):

One way of solving this would be the following:

```
day <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
diffFromNearest <- function(x, modulus) {
  dif <- x %% modulus
  ifelse(dif > modulus %/% 2, modulus - dif, dif)
}
diffFromNearest(day, 7)

 [1] 0 1 2 3 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: I can't comment on other people's answers yet, but it should be noted that BondedDust's code above relies on the data not only starting and stopping on a natural boundary, but also being symmetric with respect to the diffFromNearest function. It will only work where diffFromNearest(x, modulus) == rev(diffFromNearest(x, modulus)). If the sample data given was something arbitrary like day <- c(1,9,14,2,6,4,7,15,5) then @BondedDust's code wouldn't work.